# How to show that this sequence is a Cauchy sequence?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

let $u(m,n)_{m,n\in \mathbb{N}}$ be a double sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ that converges uniformly to $v(n)$ in $\mathbb{R}$.

Suppose also that for each $m\in \mathbb{N}$ the sequence $u(m,n)$ has a limit in $\mathbb{R}$:

$lim_{n\to\infty} u(m,n) = w(m)$

How do I show that $w(m)_{m\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a Cauchy sequnce in $\mathbb{R}$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix an $\epsilon > 0$.

Since $u(m,n)$ converges uniformly to $v(n)$ as $m \to \infty$, there exists an $M$ such that
$$ m > M \implies |u(m,n) - v (n) | < \epsilon / 4$$
for all $n \in\mathbb N$.

For any fixed $m$, the sequence $u(m,n)$ converges to $w(m)$ as $n \to \infty$, so there exists an $N_m$, whose value depends on the original choice of $m$, such that
$$ n > N_m \implies | w(m) - u(m,n) | < \epsilon / 4. $$

Now, given any two $m, m' > M$, one can pick an $n_{m,m'} > \max(N_{m}, N_{m'})$. Then
$$ |w(m) - w(m') |  \leq |w(m) - u(m,n_{m,m'})| + |u(m,n_{m,m'}) - v(n_{m,m'})| + |v(n_{m,m'}) - u(m',n_{m,m'})| \dots + |u(m',n_{m,m'}) - w(m')|  < \epsilon. $$
This shows that $w(m)$ is a Cauchy sequence.